# Value of list does not change when elements are added in each block

Tags: elixir

I have an empty list

```
val = []
```

When the code below is run

```
Enum.each [1, 2, 3], fn x ->
  IO.puts x
end
```

We get the following output.

```
1
2
3
:ok
```

That means, the elements can be accessed in the each block.

Now, when I run the below code:

```
Enum.each [1, 2, 3], fn x ->
  IO.puts x
  val = val ++ [x]
end
```

This gives the following result

```
1
2
3
:ok
```

But the value of `val` hasn't changed, it is still `[]`.

If I separately run on iex

```
val = val ++ [1]
```

The value of `val` changes to [1].

I am new to elixir with experience in ruby. Need to understand the reason behind above behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. The future versions of Elixir might even issue a warning if you try to rebind an outer variable inside an inner scope (that rebound variable is immediately discarded as the scope is left,) that said the code above three times rebinds the outer `[]` to `[i]` and effectively discards it afterwards.

To achieve what you want, use any reducer, e.g. [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```rb
Enum.reduce [1, 2, 3], [], fn x, val ->
  IO.puts x
  val ++ [x] # returning an accumulator
end
#⇒ 1
#  2
#  3

#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
```

---

*Sidenote:* in Ruby it’s also considered to be a code smell to leak accumulator variable out of the scope and/or mixing scopes:

```rb
# BAD
val = []
[1, 2, 3].each(&val.method(:<<))

# GOOD
val = [1, 2, 3].reduce([]) { |acc, e| acc << e }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. In ruby, I generally use `inject` in such cases.

Comment: `Enumerable#inject` is an alias for `Enumerable#reduce` (or vice versa.)

Comment: It is a bit odd to see this happen. Why would anybody want to discard the changes to variable as soon as the scope is left. This seems fine if we had an argument with the same name.

Comment: There is no such thing as “changes to variable” in Elixir. **Everything** in Elixir is immutable (there are some exceptions, but they are beyond the normal development flow.) That said, one cannot change the value of anything. One can rebind the variable, but this rebound variable should obviously die with the scope, otherwise, we’ll end up with billions of defined variables. Inner `val` has **nothing** to do with the outer (well, save for they share the name.)

Comment: This sounds a bit mind-blowing when switching from any language allowing mutability, but it pays back very well: one cannot _modify_ a map, a list, anything in Elixir. When needed, you just produce a new map/list/anything, sometimes with the same name. The latter is called “rebinding.“

Comment: Yes, It is a little overwhelming.
After rebinding, do these variables get deleted as soon as they come out of the function's scope or they wait for the garbage collecter to delete them?

Comment: One might assume without a loss of generality that they are deleted immediately.